# Скачивание файла, который находится за функцией

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, автоматизация

На [данной странице](https://fstec.ru/tekhnicheskaya-zashchita-informatsii/dokumenty-po-sertifikatsii/153-sistema-sertifikatsii/591-gosudarstvennyj-reestr-sertifitsirovannykh-sredstv-zashchity-informatsii-n-ross-ru-0001-01bi00) можно скачать файл: [image: ссылка для скачивания]

при нажатии мышкой, проблем не возникает, однако появляются трудности при попытке автоматизации данного действия, наводя мышкой на область скачивания, появляется ссылка - https://fstec.ru/component/attachments/download/489 ; после перехода по ней, сайт возвращает 404 ошибку, очевидно, что после клика мышкой, происходит обработка, позволяющая скачать данный файл.
Вопрос. Как, если вообще возможно, реализовать скачивание этого файла в Python через консоль (не прибегая к библиотекам GUI-автоматизации)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl 'https://fstec.ru/component/attachments/download/489'  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36 OPR/74.0.3911.160'   -H 'Referer: https://fstec.ru/tekhnicheskaya-zashchita-informatsii/dokumenty-po-sertifikatsii/153-sistema-sertifikatsii/591-gosudarstvennyj-reestr-sertifitsirovannykh-sredstv-zashchity-informatsii-n-ross-ru-0001-01bi00'
```

User-Agent и Referer вроде достаточно чтоб скачать файл